# Outlook Addin creation has permanently changed default subject/body of email. How do I revert?

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin

I tried creating Outlook plugin/add-in and followed the test instructions here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx

When I hit F5, there was an error displayed that versions were incompatible. I tried my best and uninstalled the Visual Studio.

Now whenever I reply/create new email, the subject and content changes to "This text was added by using code". How can I stop this ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check in registry if this add-in is installed. Text may be coming from this add-in. Check in registry HKCU->Software->Microsoft->Office->addin and if it is there , delete the registry key for add-in.